# Azure Hosted VM's IIS Connection

Tags: entity-framework, azure, iis, virtual-machine, iis-8

I have a .NET Application Service for IIS. I use this for maintaining user session on mobile Application. When I host this service on my local windows server and my localhost, it returns me a valid toked and expiry time for a user.

[image: Local Server]

The problem is when I host this on my Azure VM's IIS, it returns invalid grant type for the same parameters.

[image: Azure VM]

I have no idea why this is happening. I searched a lot but couldn't reach a definite solution.

In both the cases I am providing the same request body.
[image: Request]

Any pointers would be a great help,
Thanks!

EDIT

After a lot of Debugging I found that this is causing the error and the action is directly going into the `catch` clause. Here `Users` is `System.Data.Entity.DbSet`. This piece of code is running perfectly on local servers but not on azure connections.

```
Users userData = _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == user.UserName && x.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the HTTP response?

Comment: Status is 200 OK, @Nick.McDermaid